# price range filter in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

I want to filter products by price range from min price to max price. I tried but I am getting all products. Please suggest to me how can I do that?

```py
    def search(request):
        price_from = request.GET.get('price_from', None)
        price_to = request.GET.get('price_to', None)
        products = Product.objects.filter(price__range=(price_from,price_to))
    
        context = {
            'price_from': price_from,
            'price_to': price_to,
            'products': products,
        }
    
        return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

**my template code**

```html
    <div class="range-slider">
        <form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="price-input">
                <label for="amount">PriceFrom </label>
                <input type="number" name="price_from"  value="{{price_from}}">
            </div>
             <div class="price-input">
                <label for="amount">PriceTo</label>
                <input type="number" name="price_to"  value="{{price_to}}">
            </div>
            <button class="filter-btn">filter</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="range-slider">
          <form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %}" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <div class="price-input">
            <label for="amount">PriceFrom </label>
#Just Apply For loop for evry price form
            {% for i in price form %}
            <input type="number" name="price_from"  value="{{price_from}}">
            {% end for %}
           </div>
          <div class="price-input">
            <label for="amount">PriceTo</label>
            {% for i in price to %}
            <input type="number" name="price_to"  value="{{price_to}}">
            {% end for %}
          </div>
          <button class="filter-btn">filter</button>
         </form>
          </div>
</div>
```

Tell me if this worked for you

Comment: it's done. I used that format in view.py, 'products = Product.objects.filter(price__range=[price_from, price_to])'